# WSO2 ESB support for JSONPath

Tags: jsonpath, wso2-esb

I'm currently using WSO2 ESB 4.6 version. Does it support JSONPath to perform content based routing on JSON payload?

Answer (score 1):

Well, WSO2 ESB 4.8 onward it support JSONPath. You can get the details on the release below. You have to use " json-eval(JSON Path) "  to parse JSPNPath.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/About+this+Release